# Rolling out own permission app or modifying django permission

Tags: django, permissions

I am working on a project which needs a separate admin interface. The django `admin` interface is for the `super super user`, there will be companies who will sign up for our app and then they will have their own admin interface. Everything is set and done despite the permission. We want `model level permission` that's what Django provides.

What I did is:

```
class CompanyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permissions)
```

Now this list all the permissions of the site itself. So, Should I start working on my own permission app or I can modify django `Permissions` to provide object level permissions for only some models.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the several existing 'row level' / 'per object' permissions apps for Django:

http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/
http://django-object-permissions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

...there are probably others, those are just the first two in Google

We are using django-guardian in current project at work, seems fine.

I am assuming that you need to control access to sub-sets of each model's objects, depending on which company the current user belongs to (i.e. you don't want people from Company A to see items from Company B). For this reason you need *row level permissions*.

You probably also need to limit the permissions of all 'company users' to only certain actions:

- You do not need to create a `CompanyGroup` class.
- Instead just enable the admin site, log in as super user and create a `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` which contains the global permissions applicable to company users.
- then ensure when you create any new company user logins that they are added to that `Group`

Comment: Damn! There was a little typo in the question. We want the same `Model level permission`.

Comment: what is your question then? have you read the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: You misunderstood my point brother. Each company sign up to our application. They have their own admin. They have their own users. So when they create their own users(users that belong to that company), I want them be able to set the permissions for them.